# Solve Laplace equation bounded by a plane and a sphere with dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a plane 1 and a sphere 2 above the plane. Can we solve the Laplace equation
$$\nabla^2\psi=0$$
with the boundary condition $\psi|_1=\psi_0$ and $\psi|_2=0$ in the region above the plane?

The opposite setting with $\psi|_1=0$ and $\psi|_2=\psi_0$ can be solved by method of images if one treats it as a problem in electrostatics. I don't know how to do this one though.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if i understand you're question correctly, but if you solve  for $\Delta \psi = 0$ with $\psi|_1=0$ and $\psi|_1=-\psi_0$ (by method of images as you said), then take $\psi' = \psi + \psi_0$, $\Delta \psi' = 0$ and $\psi'$ satisifes the given boundary conditions.

Comment: Oh no this looks like a dumb question now.... Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe you have a typo, a 1 that should be a 2. That said, how does $\psi_0$ as a function defined off the plane make sense? Is $\psi_0$ just a constant? If so then this makes sense, otherwise it seems to me that you have a type error.

Comment: \psi_0 is just a constant. So it's really the case as Jahi02 said.

Comment: That makes sense then. Nice approach.